# Memory leak in MediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync()?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, uwp

Calls to MediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync() appear to leak memory quite dramatically on Windows 10. Windows Phone seems to be OK from what I can see on the emulator. Perhaps I am missing something obvious, can anyone throw any light on this?

Repro:

- Create blank c# Universal Windows project.
- Add button to MainPage.xaml as in:

```xaml
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click me" />
```

- Add handler to MainPage.xaml.cs as in:

```
    private MediaComposition _comp = null;
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (_comp == null) {
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.mp4", UriKind.Absolute));
            var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);

            _comp = new MediaComposition();
            _comp.Clips.Add(clip);

        }

        using (ImageStream thumb = await _comp.GetThumbnailAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 0, 0, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame)) {
            Debug.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString("N0"));

        }
    }
```

- Add required using statements as recommended by VS.
- Add some short .mp4 to your assets folder and name it test.mp4
- Run in x86 and click the button a few times. Observe memory use increasing in Process Explorer or the built-in VS diagnostics. Crashes around 800MB.

Comment: Confirm. It seems like a bug in windows store platform. It reproduces in Debug and Release modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have had confirmation from Microsoft that they can reproduce and it is a bug. NOW FIXED IN LATEST WIN 10 BUILD as at 20-Nov-15